# Linq for NHibernate, ordering by a property of a nullable association

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Kindly consider this simplified scenario:

Two NHibernate Entities:

```
public class Foo {
  public virtual Bar Bar {get; set;}
}

public class Bar {
  public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I need to sort a collection of Foo by their's Bar's name. however, not all Foos have Bars assigned. For some entities it is null

The obvious:

```
Foos.OrderBy(f => f.Bar.Name)
```

Throws an Exception.

The only way I can think of to handle it is to add a formula to Foo that I can use in the OrderBy clause. I have a feeling that there got to be a better and more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

### Update

This issue is fixed in NHibernate 3.1 - https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2412

The outer join for the OrderBy is "Built In"

Comment: For my curiosity, what's the exception thrown?

Comment: Had same problem. I just made sure every foo has its bar despite that Name could be empty. But that's a workaround...

Comment: I have experimented with some methods and now, after adding .Fetch(f => f.Bar) I can do the sorting, the problem now is that the returned results are only the ones with a Bar value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a join to Bar

If you're using NHibernate >=3.0.

```cs
from foo in session.Query<Foo>()
join bar in session.Query<Bar>() on foo.Bar.Id equals bar.Id into leftJoinFooBar
from bars in leftJoinFooBar.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby bars.Name
select foo
```

if you/re using NHibernate <3.0. You'll have to use Criteria or HQL.

Comment: hmm... that looks interesting. will check it out tomorrow

Comment: It didn't work. got NHibernate exception - operation is unsupported

Comment: Are you using NHibernation 3.x? Sounds like you might have to use QueryOver, Criteria, or HQL. The linq provider is not as powerful as the aforementioned 3 methods.

Comment: Apparently this was fixed in 3.1 (I was on 3.0) ( http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2412 ) Actually now OrderBy works without any need for join. the outer join is "Built In". I'll accept this answer however as it did get me closer to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Bar is null and pick a default string value if it is otherwise use Bar.name:

```
Foos.OrderBy(f => (f.Bar != null)?f.Bar.Name:"")
```

Comment: I doubt NHibernate Linq provider can parse that out :/

Comment: This indeed is not supported by the NH Linq provider